# error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure PHP curl

Tags: php, curl, openssl

I've been stuck on this issue for just about a day now and this is my last hope. I'm trying to establish a connetion with gov (tax) so I have to make a curl on the server with all the required data and certificates. However, I can't seem to get past this issue, for I have no idea what the underlying problem is - the certificate/s or something else.

Communication:

```
* Trying [REMOTE_IP]...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to [REMOTE_DNS] ([REMOTE_IP]) port 9002 (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: [CERT_LOCATION]
  CApath: none
* error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure
* stopped the pause stream!
* Closing connection 0
```

The code I use to create the request:

```
$conn = curl_init();
$settings = array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $this->url2post,
    CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT => true,
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS => 3000,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS => 3000,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $this->urlPostHeader,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $this->xmlMessage,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => true,
    CURLOPT_SSLCERT => $this->myCertificatePathPem,
    CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD => $this->myCertificatePassword,
    CURLOPT_CAINFO => $this->fursCertificatePath,
    CURLOPT_SSLVERSION => 6,

    CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true,
    CURLOPT_STDERR => $verbose
);
```

Also: I have to use TLS 1.2, as is required by the gov

I would appreciate any input/help!

Comment: What OS version? What PHP version? I'm guessing you've got an old OS and/or PHP version that's compiled without support for the minimum requirement.

Comment: SSLV3 errors usually mean the site you are going to hasn't updated openssl.  And that's a REALLY bad thing.  Maybe this gov site you are going to isn't really a gov site.

Comment: I'm using, on dev, windows 7 and PHP 7, as for the gov site, it indeed is the correct url, do you think the issue could be in their certificate? I really can't think of anything else

Comment: Apprently the reason was bad certificate from their part as I suspected, it works on production, so it must be the test certificate